# Unity to ios Notch And Safe Are Problems

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I have tried creating a game in unity and build it on ios on any apple devices there were no problem except on iphone x. Screenshot is below.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14nKA.png). It was covered by the iphone x notch and then when when the character is on the left or the right side it was cut it half.Is there any other solution or a plugin we can use to solve the issue ?. Is there a unity settins or xcode settings to that ? .Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

About the iPhone X notch, you can use [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/iphone-x-notch-in-screen.495028/):

```
Screen.safeArea
```

It is a convenient way to determine the screen actual "Safe Area". Read more about it in [this thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/iphone-x-notch-in-screen.495028/).

About the character cutting in half, this is probably something you need to take care of manually based on your game logic. By getting the `Screen.width` - you should be able to either adjust the Camera (zoom out) or limit the character movement in a way that it will not get past the screen edge.

Comment: thanks for idea man , what I did is that i created a code that will be able to detect the device type which is (iphonex) and if its true then it will automatically adjust the camera , i think that is the best way to do it . and also on other parts like canvas same thing detect device type and then adjust manually.

Comment: @DulfKoher That is also a way to solve it :) Just notice that more devices with notchs are going to come out soon (there are actually others out there now). When using Screen.safeArea - you can provide a solution for all cases (if Unity team will keep it alive as they should) - While providing a specific solution for iPhone X is good - it is not very robust.

Comment: one thing to be aware of is that Screen.safeArea returns actual safeArea only once Unity view is initialized. I tried calling from Awake() of a -90 priority script first, and it would return just full screen area there... moving it to Start() fixed the problem.

Answer (score 4):

For the iPhone X and other notched phones you can use the generic Screen.safeArea provided by Unity 2017.2.1+. Attach the script below to a full screen UI panel (Anchor 0,0 to 1,1; Pivot 0.5,0.5) and it will shape itself to the screen safe.

Also recommended to have your Canvas set to "Scale With Screen Size" and "Match (Width-Height)" = 0.5.

```
public class SafeArea : MonoBehaviour
{
    RectTransform Panel;
    Rect LastSafeArea = new Rect (0, 0, 0, 0);

    void Awake ()
    {
        Panel = GetComponent<RectTransform> ();
        Refresh ();
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        Refresh ();
    }

    void Refresh ()
    {
        Rect safeArea = GetSafeArea ();

        if (safeArea != LastSafeArea)
            ApplySafeArea (safeArea);
    }

    Rect GetSafeArea ()
    {
        return Screen.safeArea;
    }

    void ApplySafeArea (Rect r)
    {
        LastSafeArea = r;

        Vector2 anchorMin = r.position;
        Vector2 anchorMax = r.position + r.size;
        anchorMin.x /= Screen.width;
        anchorMin.y /= Screen.height;
        anchorMax.x /= Screen.width;
        anchorMax.y /= Screen.height;
        Panel.anchorMin = anchorMin;
        Panel.anchorMax = anchorMax;
    }
}
```

For a more in depth breakdown, I've written a detailed article with screenshots here: https://connect.unity.com/p/updating-your-gui-for-the-iphone-x-and-other-notched-devices. Hope it helps!

Comment: @CthulhuJon Currently the Screen.safeArea only works in 2017.2.1+. For Android notch support, a Unity dev has stated that it's currently in progress for a v2018.3 or above release and likely won't be backported to 2017.4. https://forum.unity.com/threads/538924/#post-3816202. Given this info, it seems unlikely the system will be backported to 5.6 unfortunately.

Comment: If iOS.DeviceGeneration could return the X series values in 5.6 then you could possibly hardcode a manual safe area system similar to the way I create a simulation safe area in the article, but I don't believe they have or will patch those new device enums into 5.6. If there is a way to detect iPhone X on 5.6 using a plugin or some other means you could do it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer but I have adjusted the camera's viewport rectangle for iOS devices and it works correctly. Check if it works for your camera as well.

I have tried safeArea and other script based solutions which do not seem to work.

```
#if UNITY_IPHONE
        mainCamera.rect = new Rect(0.06f, 0.06f, 0.88f, 1);
#endif
```